# TableA (not aggregated) left join on a aggregated TableB

Tags: sql, join, aggregate

I have two tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI84Q.png) and I want to left join Table_A to Table_B (result: all Rows from Table_A and only matching rows from Table_B)

Requirements

- I need only 2 fields from Table_B (Key and Text) and I have to group these 2 Fields. I do not need any values from Table_B.
- I need Table_A completely without any aggregation. The Join should be on Field "Key".

I already tried this forum here and found another thread with join an a aggregated table, but this did not work because it aggregated Table_A as well and trying the same without aggregating Table_A did not work.

My try:

```sql
Select * From TABLE-A
left join
(select TABLE-B.Key, TABLE-B.Text from TABLE-B
   group by TABLE-B.Key, TABLE-B.Text
 )
 On Left TABLE-A.Key = TABLE-B.Key
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you join tables, but your select is returning field values and trying to join that to a table.
You also didn't indicate what database you're using, which may have variations.

Here's what I did in MS-Access:

1. Create a new View (query) to handle the aggregate; I called it `vTableB`:

   ```sql
   SELECT [TABLE-B].Key, [TABLE-B].Text1
   FROM [TABLE-B]
   GROUP BY [TABLE-B].Key, [TABLE-B].Text1;
   ```
2. Perform your desired join against table A and the view:

   ```sql
   SELECT [TABLE-A].*
   FROM [TABLE-A] 
   LEFT JOIN vTableB ON [TABLE-A].Key = vTableB.Key;
   ```

Make changes to use your desired field names (note: your field names I don't recommend because of potential conflicts with other keywords) and see if you get the desired results.